# Advanced Nav Drivers and ROS

Tags: ros, imu, gps

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Just wondering if anyone has had any success in integrating this device into ROS:
http://www.advancednavigation.com.au/product/spatial

I think I have found a suitable driver:
https://github.com/labust/sensors-ros-pkg
but there seems to be no information on how to use the driver or what parameters are to be passed to it, and it has been almost a year since it was last touched.

passing the command:
rosrun spatial_ins spatial_node

create the topics /fix /imu and /ned_vel but nothing is published to them.

I think I have the drivers working correctly but how do I find out what arguments to pass or what arguments I could potentially pass.

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209181/advanced-nav-drivers-and-ros/) by [new2ros](https://answers.ros.org/users/21455/new2ros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 50 on 2015-05-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have created an example driver for the range of Advance Navigation INS devices eg Spatial, Spatial Dual, Spatial FOG, Spatial FOG Dual, Motus, and Orientus.

The repository can be found here: https://github.com/an-scott/Advanced_Navigation_driver.

If anyone has any questions, do not hesitate to contact me.

Scott O'Brien

Application Support Engineer

Phone: +61 2 9099 3800

Advanced Navigation

https://www.advancednavigation.com.au

---

Originally posted by [scott](https://answers.ros.org/users/31321/scott/) with karma: 36 on 2017-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KrishKannan_007](https://answers.ros.org/users/41611/krishkannan_007/) on 2019-09-13**:
Hi scott,
This is krishnakumar from Titan India, We bought a Spatial INS for our AGV application, We read the data and there is no update in linear acceleration. And we need the position of the AGV. We are having ros-melodic in our GPU.
thanq..

**Comment by [scott](https://answers.ros.org/users/31321/scott/) on 2019-09-15**:
Hello Krishnakumar ,
This ROS driver is a very basic example that shows you how to output data from Spatial and publish it as ROS messages. It does not include every function, packet or message. It is for you to extend it to suit your specific application. Other customers have done this and you can find some of their drivers on Github - look for Forks.